# Using promises to GET and process data

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, meteor

I'm working on a Meteor application which integrates a user's contacts from external sources (Google in the case of this example). I'm currently writing the server side code to retrieve this data and send it to the client.

I figured using promises to do this made sense due to the asynchronous manner of requests. So I have `getContacts` which sends the request to the Google API, and `processContacts` which processes and formats the response data:

```
getContacts = function (accessToken) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    httpRequest.get({
      url: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json',
      auth: {
        'bearer': accessToken
      },
      headers: {
        'GData-Version': 3.0
      },
    }, function (err, res, body) {
      resolve(body);
    });
  });
}

processContacts = function(googleContacts) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    const contacts    = JSON.parse(googleContacts).feed.entry;
    const allContacts = [];
    const groupedContacts = { conflicts: [], new: [] };
    ...    
    ...
    resolve(groupedContacts);
  });
}
```

I have a Meteor method `google.contacts.import` which is called synchronously from the client, and because all of this is asynchronous I'm using a future to force the client to wait for the call to finish:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'google.integration.import'(orgId) {
    check(orgId, String);

    const user = Users.getOne(Meteor.userId());
    let fut = new Future();

    getContacts(user.services.google.accessToken)
    .then(processContacts)
    .then(function(contacts){
      fut.return(contacts);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log('error! :' + err);
    });

    return fut.wait();
  },
})
```

This all works fine, but it seems...messy or somewhat convoluted. I'm relatively new to Javascript and ES6 in particular so I feel I could definitely improve this. Am I correct to be using promises here? I guess they probably aren't necessary in the case of `processContacts`. I also realize this is lacking in terms of error checking/reporting.

Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think the preferred way to handle async on the server in Meteor is to use fiber aware async functions, e.g. use the `http` Meteor package which gives you fiber aware "sync" style calls on the server (you write it like a sync call but it does not block the thread) and standard async callback signature on the client.

Also, I am not sure about using futures on the client, is there even a `fibers` environment running on the client?  Instead, I think you just pass a standard callback to `Meteor.call` to handle the results of the method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are fine to use promises here, although I agree that a promise is not necessarily required for `processContacts`. Not sure if this was helpful.

*EDIT*: Because of the nature of your program, `processContacts` is going to be asynchronous no matter what, so using a promise is not a bad idea.